# Wordpress Code Based On Date

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to get Wordpress to execute some code if the post date is later than a particular date. When I use the following, it almost works...except Worpress shows/echos the date instead of just evaluating it.

```
<?php $date1 = '2013-03-22';
$date2 = the_date();
if ($date2 >= $date1) { ?>

//code to execute

<?php } ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using something like this:

```
$date2 = the_date('','','',FALSE);
if (strtotime($date2) >= strtotime($date1)) { code to execute }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simply how [`the_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date) works:

> Displays or returns the date of a post, or a set of posts if published on the same day

Example usage:

```
<?php the_date( $format, $before, $after, $echo ); ?>
```

So you have to pass `false` to the function to not print the date, because it defaults to `true`. For example:

```
<?php
$date1 = '2013-03-22';
$date2 = the_date('', '', '', FALSE);
if ($date2 >= $date1): ?>
  Hello world!
<? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
$date1 = '2013-03-22';
$date2 = get_the_date();
if ($date2 >= $date1) { ?>
   //code to execute
<?php } ?>
```

`get_the_date()` just returns the date while `the_date()` prints the post date.